# how to fix this module error for total=getCost

Tags: python, python-3.8

I am trying to calculate the total = getCost but it keeps saying its unsupported operand type. my previous one looks similar to this setup and it works fine. not sure why this isn't working.
    here is the code.

```
 def main():
        mealPrice = getPrice()
        tip = getTip(mealPrice)
        tax = getTax(mealPrice)
        total = getCost(mealPrice, tip, tax)
        printgetInfo(mealPrice, tip, tax, total)

    def getPrice():
        mealPrice = input('Enter the meal price $ ')
        mealPrice = float(mealPrice)
        return mealPrice


    def getTip(mealPrice):
        if (mealPrice >= .01)and(mealPrice <= 5.99):
            tip = mealPrice *.10
        elif (mealPrice >= 6)and(mealPrice <= 12):
            tip = mealPrice *.13
        elif (mealPrice >= 12.01)and(mealPrice <= 17):
            tip = mealPrice *.16
        elif (mealPrice >= 17.01)and(mealPrice <= 25):
            tip = mealPrice *.19
        else:
            tip = mealPrice *.22
            return tip


    def getTax(mealPrice):
        tax = mealPrice * .06
        return tax


    def getCost(mealPrice, tip, tax):
        total = mealPrice + tip + tax
        return total

    def getInfo(mealPrice, tip, tax, total):
        print('The meal price is $', mealPrice)
        print('The tip is $', tip)
        print('The tax is $', tax)
        #print('The total amount is $' total)


    main()
```

Comment: Include the Traceback, formatted as code. where is the data? Any chance of a **minimal** [mcve]?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\aswanx\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Documents\lab 5.py", line 44, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\aswanx\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Documents\lab 5.py", line 5, in main
    total = getCost(mealPrice, tip, tax)
  File "C:\Users\aswanx\OneDrive - Intel Corporation\Documents\lab 5.py", line 34, in getCost
    total = mealPrice + tip + tax
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: I figured out what I did wrong. the return tip was indented.